# How to make elements with the same "src"

Tags: src

I have two elements , element[a] has (src) which is linked to a video , and element[b] has (src) which has no link {src=""} , how can i make all these elements have same (src) as i click on element[a]. Thanks in advance

````
element[a]

<p class="cot">
<a src="golight_vid/Israel_Mbonyi_-_Mbwira(360p).mp4" id="lik" onclick="document.getElementById('pl').style.display='block'" align="center">
</a></p>



element[b]

<div id="pl" class="veiw" align="center">
<video class="ply" controls autoplay loop>
   <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your HTML:

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById("lik").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const newSrc = "https://www.example.com/video.mp4";
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#lik,#pl,video.ply>source"); //change #b for the real id

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].src = newSrc;
    };
  });
</script>
```

Here, you're attaching a function to the click event of element A, so that it runs each time you click it. In the function, you define the new src you wish to apply, as well as a list of elements you wish to apply it to. You can modify these to your liking. Using ids (`#id`) is the simplest way to refer to specific elements.

The function then loops through those elements and applies the src.

Comment: Which #Id should I add instead of #b ?

Comment: Whatever the `id` value of 'element[b]' is (e.g. `#pl` if it's that one).